# How to open Deep Link in Expo Dev Client

Tags: react-native, react-router, expo, deep-linking

I recently added the `dev-client` in my Expo (Bare Workflow) React Native App. The deep linking configuration was working fine earlier with my scheme as:

`scheme://mobile-prefix/product/10`

In the local environment, I tried using the local development Deep-link as follows:

```
scheme://expo-development-client/?url=http://192.168.5.80:8081
```

This opened the app ^. This was according to the documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/development/development-workflows/#deep-linking-urls

But it still isn't clear how do I open the deep link say to a particular product which was earlier: `mobile-prefix/product/10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to make it work was:

1. Create development build.
2. Then use the local scheme URI, like below. See screenshot for reference

```
scheme://192.168.5.80:8081/mobile-prefix/product/10
```

So the above URI works ^

where `mobile-prefix/product/10` is the one configured on React Native App itself.

[image]

Comment: Does it work with React Navigation?

Comment: Yes, works with React Navigation.

Comment: @YM would you happen to know the answer to this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74260423/react-native-expo-opening-up-the-dev-client-app-via-qr-code

Answer (score 2):

I was using your above answer with React Navigation which didn't work.

You might not need the IP address. Just `your-scheme-here://mobile-prefix/product/10` will work.

Comment: Would you happen to know the answer to this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74260423/react-native-expo-opening-up-the-dev-client-app-via-qr-code